# My all local cases works, but when submitting to Kattis it gives error on all except 2 cases. How can I figure it out?

Tags: python, debugging, polygon, convex-polygon

The problem is PolygonGame problem:
https://open.kattis.com/problems/polygongame

Where we start with a convex polygon, divide it by drawing straight lines from one side to the other side of the polygon, and then find the area of the biggest part and print it.

Here's the file I have where I use strings as inputs:
https://github.com/STProgrammer/problem/blob/main/polygon-game-testing.py

And here's the file I solve the same problem with shapely libraries to compare my results:
https://github.com/STProgrammer/problem/blob/main/polygon-game-with-shapely.py

In my local PC, whether I use shapely or my code, I get the same results with different inputs and cases. I checked some of them with pen and paper and the results are correct.

And here's the file for submission:
https://github.com/STProgrammer/problem/blob/main/polygon-game-submit.py

I tried the submission file with my inputs and get the same results as the two codes above.

But when I submit the code on Kattis, I get correct only the first one, the others are wrong. And as known, Kattis doesn't give feedback to results.

**How can I figure out what's the problem?**

I assumed the polygons are only convex in the problem as they mention that. My code doesn't work on concave polygons. Am I wrong about my assumption about the problem?

I run the code on Spyder with Python 3.10.10 on Windows 11. Is that the problem?

Am I missing out some edge cases?

Comment: Please share the code in the question itself, rather than an external link. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Same things has happened to me. I've discovered that reading standard in as "print()" or "sys.stdin.read()" for some reason gives completely different answers. When I've been frustrated cause my VS Code code is correct but Kattis rejects it, I've many times solved it by just switching input method to stdin.read

Comment: OP gets the sample test correct on submission, so it's likely that they have I/O set up properly. This is a hard problem, difficulty 5.9, so it's probably the algorithm/logic OP is using.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).